# Storage Server 2012 R2 SMB share permissions

Tags: windows-storage-server

I am deploying a Dell NX3200 with Storage Server 2012 R2 as a NAS in my office and I am having difficulty with accessing the shares.

My shares are defined with 4 groups.

1. System - Full Control
2. Administrators - Full Control
3. local.group.on.server - Read
4. local.group.on.server - Modify

The local groups are populated with domain users and groups, this is the easiest method in my large organisation as we have very strict rules on the creation of AD groups.

In the past this has worked quite well for us on Server 2008 R2, but for some reason on this box if I add a user to one of the local groups and they've already attempted to access the share from their client machine with a lesser privilege (for example I had someone access with no access and it denied them, then I added them to the read only group) it will fail with no access. If they reboot the client it works, if they access from a different machine it works immediately.

It seems like the client machines are caching the old "no access" rights, is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: `It seems like the client machines are caching the old "no access" rights,`  Sounds like it.  So, uh, with that in mind, can we get any details on the clients in question?

Comment: It happens on Windows 7 and 8.1 machines on the same domain as the Storage Server 2012 R2 NAS. VM, Laptop, Desktop... It doesn't matter.